# Calendar + Notes app not syncing to iCloud

Tags: icloud, data-synchronization, calendar, notes.app, ical

I have a fresh install of macOS Sonoma and am struggling to sync properly to my iCloud account (which I've only just registered).

My calendar is split into 3 different ones, so that I can have everything colour-coded.

There is only one of the calendars that is sync'ing, and even then its not fully populated on the online version. There are 1 or 2 items missing.

My others calendars aren't showing in the online version at all.

None of my notes in the Notes app are sync'ing either.

Comment: syncing might take a while, check in few hours